# Hibernate - one to one relation

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, one-to-one

I have two tables

User

```
CREATE TABLE "user"
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    phone TEXT,
    position_id BIGINT,
    CONSTRAINT user_position_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (position_id) REFERENCES position (id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_id_uindex ON "user" (id);
```

Position

```
CREATE TABLE position
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    latitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    bearing DOUBLE PRECISION,
    accuracy DOUBLE PRECISION,
    speed DOUBLE PRECISION,
    user_id BIGINT,
    CONSTRAINT position_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user" (id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX position_id_uindex ON position (id);
```

They are mapped by annotations like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String PHONE = "phone";

    public User() {
        position = new Position();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = ID, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = PHONE)
    private String phone;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "position_id")
    private Position position;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "position")
public class Position {

    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    public static final String BEARING = "bearing";
    public static final String ACCURACY = "accuracy";
    public static final String SPEED = "speed";
    public static final String USER_ID = "user_id";

    @Column(name = ID, unique = true)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
            parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "property", value = "user")})
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = LATITUDE)
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name = LONGITUDE)
    private double longitude;

    @Column(name = BEARING)
    private double bearing;

    @Column(name = ACCURACY)
    private double accuracy;

    @Column(name = SPEED)
    private double speed;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
}
```

I'm saving new object into database. Everything is correct except one thing. Fields `user_id` and `position_id` are null. Is there any solution which help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

It will take a few steps to fix your problem.

Let's start with that in One to One association there's only **one** foreign key, you can decide which entity will own the foreign key.

The `@joinColumn` annotation is supposed to be only in the owning entity, for example, if you decided that user will own the position key as a foreign key then the `@joinColumn` annotation will be in the user entity under the position field.

on the other entity just use

```
@OneToOne(mappedby = "the_matching_field_on_the_other entity")
```

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE "user"
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    phone TEXT,
    position_id BIGINT,
    CONSTRAINT user_position_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (position_id) REFERENCES position (id)
);

CREATE TABLE position
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    latitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    bearing DOUBLE PRECISION,
    accuracy DOUBLE PRECISION,
    speed DOUBLE PRECISION,
);

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")

public class User {

public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String PHONE = "phone";

public User() {
    position = new Position();
}

@Id
@Column(name = ID, unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = PHONE)
private String phone;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "position_id")
private Position position;
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "position")
public class Position {

    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    public static final String BEARING = "bearing";
    public static final String ACCURACY = "accuracy";
    public static final String SPEED = "speed";
    public static final String USER_ID = "user_id";

    @Column(name = ID, unique = true)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
            parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "property", value = "user")})
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = LATITUDE)
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name = LONGITUDE)
    private double longitude;

    @Column(name = BEARING)
    private double bearing;

    @Column(name = ACCURACY)
    private double accuracy;

    @Column(name = SPEED)
    private double speed;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "position")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: I don't sure that I understood you. You meant something like that?:
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="i don't know which field should i use")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;